# Is it possible to update word2vec model in SPARK?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, word2vec

I cannot find this, but I was wondering if someone trains a model in Spark version of word2vec. Can, later on, reload it and update when there are new data available?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It cannot be done. It needs to be trained again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!